# Django rest framework: how to change default widget of a ModelSerializer renderer with HTMLFormRenderer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to change the default widget of a ModelSerializer field renderered with the HTMLFormRenderer. The field default representation is a ChoiceField as it is a ForeignKey field in the model. I Would like to render it as a CharField.

I have tried to redefine the field in the serializer:

```
myField = serializers.CharField()
```

It is shown correctly as a textbox in the form but when saving the form I receive an error saying that it cannot assign the value because it must be an instance of the related model.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

sorry for necrobumping, but I had a similar problem today and this thread jumped high in google results. it seems one can override the `style` property, like so:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_field = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset = ...,
        style={'base_template': 'input.html'}
    )
```

I've looked in source code for HTMLFormRenderer and it uses similar attributes:

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/renderers.py#L265

Answer (score 0):

One way is to override the `to_native` and `restore_fields` functions of the serializer.

`restore_fields` essentially lets you handle the incoming request, massage it in any manner you want and save it to models. `to_native` lets you take the server data and modify it in any manner to send it to the client.

Comment: Are you refering to restore_object functions instead of restore_data?

Comment: Is there any example somewhere doing something similar?

Comment: Sorry, it is `restore_fields`.